# How the TComponent can be rendered or moved as its parent is moved?

Tags: delphi

I need a transparent component. so I decided to create a class inherited from TComponent where I use a TForm AlphaBlend. I get transparency, but when moving or re-rendering my parent form my component is not moved. how to solve?

```
unit Transparent;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  System.Classes,
  System.SysUtils,
  Vcl.Controls,
  Vcl.Forms,
  Vcl.Dialogs,
  Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Vcl.Graphics,
  System.Math,
  Winapi.Messages;

type
  TTransparent = class(TComponent)
  private
    FParent     : TWinControl;
    FBackGround : TForm;
    procedure CreateContainer;
  public
    procedure Show(aParent : TWinControl);
    procedure Close;
  end;


procedure Register;

implementation

{ TTransparent }

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Custom', [TTransparent]);
end;

procedure TTransparent.Close;
begin
  FreeAndNil(FBackGround);
end;

procedure TTransparent.CreateContainer;
var
  vParentOrigin: TPoint;
begin
  if FParent = nil then
    FParent := Application.MainForm;

  FBackGround                 := TForm.Create(nil);
  FBackGround.AlphaBlend      := True;
  FBackGround.AlphaBlendValue := 200;
  FBackGround.BorderStyle     := bsNone;
  FBackGround.Color           := clBlack;

  vParentOrigin := FParent.ClientOrigin;
  SetWindowPos(
    FBackGround.Handle,
    HWND_TOP,
    vParentOrigin.X,
    vParentOrigin.Y,
    FParent.ClientWidth - 1,
    FParent.ClientHeight,
    SWP_SHOWWINDOW
  );
end;

procedure TTransparent.Show(aParent: TWinControl);
begin
  FParent := aParent;
  CreateContainer
end;

end.
```

```
object Form5: TForm5
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form5'
  ClientHeight = 302
  ClientWidth = 418
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 160
    Top = 240
    Width = 75
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Button1'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
  object Transparent1: TTransparent
    Left = 320
    Top = 32
  end
end
```

```
unit Principal;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Transparent, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm5 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Transparent1: TTransparent;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form5: TForm5;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Transparent1.Show(Self);
end;

end.
```

I've already used TFormComponent.Parent := TFormPai but I lose transparency

I tried using WMMove. but without success. Look:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You are not setting `FBackGround.Parent`, so `FBackGround` has a free-floating window with no relation to your `FParent` window. To fix that, you will have to either:

- set `FBackGround.Parent := FParent`, but know that you will lose your `AlphaBlend` capability on Windows 7 and earlier, AND on Windows 8+ if your application manifest *does not* claim Windows 8 compatibility.
- hook `FParent` to track its movements so you can then move `FBackGround` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a solution to my problem.

1. I didn't define the father
2. I used the procedure method WndProc(var Msg: TMessage)

This way I can move my transparency according to the main Form

```
Create:
FComponentOwner := GetParentForm(TControl(AOwner));
  if (FComponentOwner <> nil) and not (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
  begin
    FOrgWndProc := FComponentOwner.WindowProc;
    FComponentOwner.WindowProc := WndProc;
  end;

Destroy:
if FComponentOwner <> nil then
begin
  if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
    FComponentOwner.WindowProc := FOrgWndProc;
  FComponentOwner := nil;
end;

procedure TTransparent.WndProc(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
  if Assigned(FOrgWndProc) then
    FOrgWndProc(Msg);

  if Msg.Msg = CM_RELEASE then
    Exit;

  case Msg.Msg of
    WM_MOVE, WM_MOVING, WM_SIZE, WM_SIZING:
      if (Self <> nil) and (FComponentOwner <> nil) then
        setPositionOpacity;

    WM_SETFOCUS:
      if (Self <> nil) and Self.Visible then
        Self.Perform(Msg.Msg, Msg.WParam, Msg.LParam);
  end;

end;
```